# Множественная выборка через checkBox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Всем привет! Не могу реализовать множественную выборку через отмеченные конкретные чекбоксы.Сервер видит отмечены ли они,сколько их отмечено,но вот не могу понять что нужно изменить или добавить что-либо в код чтобы сделать выборку конкретно выбранную чекбоксами вот допустим после WHERE что туда писать ума не приложу

чекбокс

```
    <div class="tops col-md-2 mt-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input name="topics[]" class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox" value=1   id="topics" >
<!--            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  id="topics" >-->
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                <?=$value['name_topic']?>
            </label>
        </div>

      </div>
```

обработчик

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../DB.php';

    if (isset($_POST['topics'])) {

        $top = $_POST['topics'];


        if (!empty($top)) {

            foreach ($top as $checkVal) {


                if ($checkVal == 1) {


            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `topic` WHERE ';
            global $connect;
            $query = $connect->prepare($sql); 
            $query->execute();

            $topic = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `where id IN (1,2,3)` видимо? проверить что передано число, сложить встроку и пихнуть в запрос. либо нагенерить плейсхолдеров, и пихнуть в запрос параметрами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем в инпуте изменил значение с 1 ,на значение которое хранит в себе id категории

```
  <input name="topics[]" class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox" value="<?=$value['id']?>"   id="topics" >
```

После чего в обработчике мы просто проверяем массив данных на пустоту,если все отлично,то выбираем  из связанной таблицы ПОСТОВ категорию к которой он принадлежит по id категории,котоый мы ранее поместили в значение инпута
А для правильной передачи после WHERE массива значений использовал функцию implode и подставил в запрос.

```
$id = $top;
                $matches = implode(',', $id);
                $sqlP = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE id_topic IN ($matches)";
```

Comment: `$matches = implode(',', array_map(function ($i) { return (int)$i; }, $id));`

Answer (score -1):

where "поле_в_бд" = "1_значение" or "поле_в_бд" = "2_значение"  or "поле_в_бд" = "3_значение"